# Adding and Deleting in ES6 Javascript Alone

Tags: javascript, beginner, ecmascript-6, dom

I need help in making this as short as possible and it should follow the latest ES6 standards. It it already 100% working. But I need help because i want to follow the best practices in using ES6. The code is a little bit long and messy so maybe you can help me edit my code to make it short and clean. I'm just beginning to learn ES6 so i badly needed your professional advice. Specifically, I want help in implementing on how to output table correctly and declaring variables using ES6.

```js
const products = [];
const cart = [];
const inputs = {
  id: document.getElementById("productID"),
  desc: document.getElementById("product_desc"),
  qty: document.getElementById("quantity"),
  price: document.getElementById("price")
};
const productsTable = document.getElementById("products-table");
const cartsTable = document.getElementById("carts-table");

function renderProductsTable() {
  // delete all entries
  [].slice.call(productsTable.children, 1).forEach(entry => productsTable.removeChild(entry));

  products.forEach(product => {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    const id = document.createElement('td');
    id.textContent = product.id;
    const desc = document.createElement('td');
    desc.textContent = product.desc;
    const qty = document.createElement('td');
    qty.textContent = product.qty;
    const price = document.createElement('td');
    price.textContent = product.price;
    const action = document.createElement('td');
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', removeProduct.bind(null, product.id));
    const addToCartButton = document.createElement('button');
    

    action.appendChild(deleteButton);
   

    tr.appendChild(id);
    tr.appendChild(desc);
    tr.appendChild(qty);
    tr.appendChild(price);
    tr.appendChild(action);
    productsTable.appendChild(tr);
  });
}

function addProduct() {
  const product = {
    id: inputs.id.value,
    desc: inputs.desc.value,
    qty: inputs.qty.value,
    price: inputs.price.value
  };
  console.log(products);

  products.push(product);
  renderProductsTable();
  document.getElementById('order').reset();
}
function removeProduct(product_id) {
  const product = products.find(p => p.id === product_id);
  const index = products.indexOf(product);
  products.splice(index, 1);
  renderProductsTable();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Shopping Cart ES6</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="order" id="order">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="productID">Product ID:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="productID" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <label for="product">Product Desc:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
              <input id="product_desc" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
              <input id="quantity" name="quantity" width="196px" required/>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <label for="price">Price:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
              <input id="price" name="price" size="28" required/>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="reset" class="resetbtn" value="Reset" />
  <input type="button" id="btnAddProduct" onclick="addProduct();" value="Add New Product" >
</form>
<table border="1|1" id="products-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Product ID</th>
    <th>Product Description</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The guidelines here say that you should describe in your description what exactly your code is supposed to do.

Comment: @jfriend00. I just need help in revising my codes to adhere to the ES6 Standards. Maybe you can help me with that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

as mentioned previously you are using a lot of ES6 already but you can clean things up a bit more and you seem to want to see it written so here is my attempt below.

I have added in what has been mentioned already as well as some other ES6 helpfullness such as string interpolation.

I have also added in a small bit of validation so that the product id is unique, should be expanded upon but is a start.

https://jsfiddle.net/hpyj1acs/

## JavaScript

```
function renderProductsTable(e) {
    // delete all entries
    [...productsTable.children].slice(1).forEach(entry => productsTable.removeChild(entry));

    products.forEach(product => {
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.innerHTML = `<td>${ product.productId }</td>
                        <td>${ product.desc }</td>
                        <td>${ product.qty }</td>
                        <td>${ product.price }</td>
                        <td>
                            <button id="${ product.productId }">Delete</button>
                            <button id="${ product.productId }">Add to Cart</button>
                        </td>`;

        productsTable.appendChild(tr);

        document.getElementById(product.productId).onclick = () => removeProduct(product.productId);
    });
}

function validProduct(){
    let productIsValid = true;
    products.forEach(product => {
        if(Object.values(product).includes(inputs.productId.value)){
            productIsValid = false;
        }else{
            productIsValid = !!(inputs.productId.value && inputs.desc.value && inputs.qty.value && inputs.price.value)
        }
    });
    return productIsValid;
}

function addProduct() {
    if(validProduct()){
        const product = {
            productId: inputs.productId.value,
            desc: inputs.desc.value,
            qty: inputs.qty.value,
            price: inputs.price.value
        };
        console.log(products);

        products.push(product);
        renderProductsTable();
        document.getElementById('order').reset();
    }
}

function removeProduct(product_id) {
    const index = products.findIndex(p => p.id === product_id);
    products.splice(index, 1);
    renderProductsTable();
}

const products = [];
const cart = [];
const inputs = {
    productId: document.getElementById("productID"),
    desc: document.getElementById("product_desc"),
    qty: document.getElementById("quantity"),
    price: document.getElementById("price")
};
const productsTable = document.getElementById("products-table");
const cartsTable = document.getElementById("carts-table");

document.getElementById('btnAddProduct').onclick = addProduct;
```

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart ES6</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="order" id="order">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="productID">Product ID:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="productID" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="product">Product Desc:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="product_desc" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" width="196px" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="price">Price:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" id="price" name="price" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="reset" class="resetbtn" value="Reset" />
    <input type="button" id="btnAddProduct" value="Add New Product" >
</form>
<table border="1|1" id="products-table">
    <tr>
        <th>Product ID</th>
        <th>Product Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to use HTML5 inputs like `number` for quantity and price (where for price, the `step` could be 0.01)

Comment: @Icepickle you are correct, I have added the number type in.

Answer (score 3):

You are already using quite a lot of ES6 features (`const`, arrow functions, `Array.prototype.find`, etc)

Here's a few more places you could use some ES6 features:

#### `Array.prototype.findIndex` / `Array.prototype.filter`

Inside `removeProduct` you are finding the product that has the same id as `product_id` and then finding the index of that through `indexOf` - this can be simplified through `findIndex`:

`const index = products.findIndex(p => p.id === product_id)`

Alternatively, we could just filter products and not worry about the index altogether:

`products = products.filter(product => product.filter !== product_id)`

#### `Array.from` / `...`

You can use `Array.from` or the spread operator to convert the `NodeList` instead of `[].slice.call`:

`Array.from(productsTable.children).slice(1).forEach(...)`

Or, using spread operator:

`[...productsTable.children].slice(1).forEach(...)`

#### Arrow function over bind

In my opinion, the following is easier to read than using `bind`:

`deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => removeProduct(product.id))`

#### Non ES6/General comments

More generally, I'd recommend being consistent with your style of camel case and renaming to `productId`

I find not abbreviating variable names helps avoid context switch. It's quite clear that `desc` is description but using `p` for `product` can become not so obvious once your codebase increases.

Comment: Sir can you make changes on my code on the snippet. I would gladly appreciate it. Thank you